# Why doesn't the thermometer go back to ambient temperature after I take my temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, instrument

These past days I had a fever and I have taken my temperature many times with the thermometer in the photo. I think this is just like a mercury thermometer, even if it's a newer one that does not contain mercury, but my question applies also to mercury thermometers.

Every time I take the temperature with a thermometer like this I have to shake it to make it go back, otherwise it stays to the higher temperature it reached for a very long time. If it works just by thermal expansion, when I'm done taking my temperature and I put it at ambient temperature shouldn't it go back? Why doesn't it?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't mean that the thermometer stays at a high temperature, but that the metal inside remains expanded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be an alcohol thermometer, designed solely for measuring body temperature.

Near the reservoir there's some kind of a 'soft' one-way valve. This prevents the alcohol from flowing back into the reservoir just after measurement, as this would lead to erroneous readings (underestimates) of the body temperature. The latter could have very serious consequences, of course.

Shaking then forces the alcohol back into the reservoir through the valve, after the themometer has cooled back to RT.

The reservoir is made of shiny metal, possibly to emulate the now defunct mercury thermometers.

---

In response to OP's comment, here's a *possible* idea for a 'soft' one way valve, for this device:

[image: OM valve]

The assymetric constriction would allow the expanding alcohol through but severely restrict flow in the other direction. The forces of repeated shaking would force the alcohol back into the reservoir.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/593185/why-doesnt-a-mercury-thermometer-follow-the-rules-of-volume-dilatation/593189#593189  The ethanol based thermometers work just the same way -- although they need a more vigorous shaking.

Comment: @Gert I would like to see an example of how such a one-way valve that allows the alcohol to flow back when you shake it would work. Do you have some references?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for accepting my answer. Wiki *might* have something on "medical thermometer". I can see how an assymetrical constriction near the reservoir, as a 'soft' OW valve could work. I'll include a diagram in the answer but gimme a bit of time.

Comment: Voila: my proposed valve, for what it's worth.

Comment: A question remains to be explained is why viscous flow not reciprocal (symmetrical); why? For somebody who has "grown up" on the flow electric charges in a homogeneous medium this is quite surprising.

Comment: @hyportnex Viscous flow through such a valve would not experience the same pressure drop for left to right v. right to left flow.

Comment: Of course but neither is the voltage the same at the ends of a resistor, there is a voltage drop that drives the charges. Take a series connection of two resistors $R_1, R_2$ , one large, one small but the current is the same whether you drive it from the "left" or from the "right". So in a steady current (\partial/\partial t =0$) would be the same, hence reciprocity.  You do not get this behavior for an inhomogeneous medium such as a semiconductor diode. So what makes the pressure drop not symmetrical while its formal analogue the voltage drop is symmetrical.

Comment: You need firstly to understand how head losses in valves work. This is a good starting point resource: https://www.pumpsandsystems.com/understand-how-valves-fittings-affect-head-loss-0 Comparing this type of valve with an electrical resistance is a very bad analogy, BTW...